# Making a "multiplying dice game" fair

Tags: probability, dice

I have probability homework due tomorrow. Here's an example problem:

> Two fair dice are rolled. If the digits of the dice multiply to form an even number, **Player A** gets **1 point**. If the product is odd, **Player B** is the one to get **1 point**. How can you make this game fair such that both players get equal chances of winning? (You can assign a point system, how many draws will there be, and how many points will players need to achieve to win. The dice cannot be made unfair.)

As I understand it, **Player A** has a **27/36** chance of getting a point per draw, while **Player B** has a **9/36** of getting a point per draw.

**How can I make this game fair?**

Comment: Give player B 3 points for each success, first to reach 100 points ?

Comment: If I can change the pips on the die, then this is trivial: it is sufficient to make one dice with all odd numbers (say 1,3,5,7,9,11 or 1,1,1,1,1,1)  and the other dice with 3 even numbers and 3 odd numbers (say, 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 1,1,1,2,2,2).

Comment: @trueblueanil had that in mind. I'll just try to explain that mathematically, thanks ;0